# Camel JMS component, how to get a callback on subscriptions?

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

I am developing a service where I need to subscribe to JMS Queues dynamically with Camel JMS 2.17.0.

So I create a listening route at runtime using a bean:

```
// Bean: createCustomListenerNow
String endpoint = "jms:queue:" + queueName +
                    "&testConnectionOnStartup=true&exceptionListener=#listenerBuilder";

// camelContext.addRoutes uses this RouteBuilder
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(endpoint)
            .id(id)
            .to("seda:processReply");
}
```

My actual broker is Websphere MQ and I may get an exception if my account doesn't have the right permissions. Unfortunately this happens **after** my route has been built.

My route goes like this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:mock" />
    <to uri="bean:createCustomListenerNow" /> <!-- I want to block here until subscription is OK -->
    <to uri="bean:doSomethingThatRequiresTheListenerToBeProperlyRunning" />
</route>
```

Is there a way to "block" until the JMS component creates a new connections and successfully subscribes? I didn't manage to find a callback or a simple way to get this information.

---

What I do now is registering a `javax.jms.ExceptionListener` and waiting for a JMSException. If the exception is not thrown before a timeout I suppose the subscription did succeed.
I don't think this approach is rock-solid, any suggestion is appreciated.

I cannot block until I receive a message on the listener because it can arrive hours later and I need to finish processing the current Exchange with a reply like "Setup of listener is ok" or "Setup of listener failed".

Comment: Alessandro, looks like you want your route to only start when a certain precondition (can connect to QM) is fulfilled. You could try to implement a route policy that checks if you can connect to the QM and only if that works, start your route.

Comment: @SebastianBrandt I like your idea. My precondition involves subscribing to a queue. Thus I need to subscribe in a transaction, rollback the transaction and let Camel setup the new route / JMS listener. I'll do some experimentation.